# Creating confidence intervals for regression curve in GLMM using Bootstrapping

Tags: r, glm, confidence-interval, statistics-bootstrap

Have created a GLMM model and plotted the predicted probabilities of each factor. However, I cannot fathom how to create confidence intervals using the BootMer function. I keep getting the error message cannot simulate from non integer prior weights.
I'm hoping someone would be able to help? Thanks in advance.

```
glmm1 <- glmer(cbind(Total_Dead, Total_Collected - Total_Dead) ~  
                 Species + timeseries + (1|Location), 
               data = dat, family= "binomial")
dat$timeseries <- dat$Study_Date - 1998

plot(predict(glmm1, data.frame(Species="An. Arab", timeseries= dat$timeseries), 
             type="response", re.form = NA) ~
       dat$timeseries, frame=FALSE, bty="n", pch="", xaxt="n", ylim=c(0, 0.5), 
     ylab="Predicted mortality", xlab="Year", 
     main = "Predicted mortality by species", 
     cex.lab=1.6, yaxt="n")
axis(1, at=c(1:17), labels=1999:2015, cex.axis=1.8)
axis(2, las=2, at=seq(0, 1, 0.2), labels=seq(0, 1, 0.2), cex.axis=1.8) 

COLS <- c("blue", "red", "purple", "aquamarine3", "orange")
PCH <- c(17, 15, 19, 20, 5)

for(i in 1:length(unique(levels(dat$Species)))){
  points((dat$Total_Dead[dat$Species == levels(dat$Species)[i]] / 
            dat$Total_Collected[dat$Species == levels(dat$Species)[i]]) ~ 
           dat$timeseries[dat$Species == levels(dat$Species)[i]], 
         pch=PCH[i], col=COLS[i])
  lines(predict(glmm1, data.frame(Species=levels(dat$Species)[i], 
                                  timeseries = dat$timeseries), type="response", 
                re.form = NA) ~ dat$timeseries, lty=4, col=COLS[i])
}

bootstrap <- bootMer(x=glmm1, FUN= fixef, nsim=200)
```

Answer (score 1):

for some reason Bootmer has problems with that, you have to use the mertools package

```
library(merTools)
preds <- predictInterval(glmm1, newdata = your.datarame, n.sims = 1000)
```

I would use then then the preds data.frame to plot, the resulting data.frame has the fit, upper and lower limit, then you can use geom_ribbon to plot it, if you need more help let me know.

now bear with me, you actually want to make a new standardized dataset for your graph. If you use this code it will work:

```
glmm1 <- glmer(cbind(Total_Dead, Total_Collected - Total_Dead) ~  
             Species + timeseries + (1|Location),
           data = dat,family= "binomial")
```

fit your model, then create your new data set, this will have your timeseries from 1 to 16 for each species, in your first location (Akron), note that you will have to do this for each location if you want the graph for each location, you can do that just by changing the number between [] from 1, to 2 up to your 17 locations

```
new.data <-data.frame(timeseries = rep(1:16, times = 5), Species = rep(unique(dat$Species), each = 16), Location = rep(unique(dat$Location)[1], each = 80))
```

Then predict the values and intervals for such dataset

```
preds <- predictInterval(glmm1, newdata = new.data, n.sims = 1000)
```

now join this prediction to your new.data

```
new.data <- cbind(new.data, preds)
```

and finally plot it with different colors for each species

```
ggplot(new.data, aes(x = timeseries, y = fit)) + geom_ribbon(aes(ymax=upr, ymin =lwr, fill=Species), alpha = 0.9)+ geom_line(aes(color=Species))
```

If you don't understand something don't hesitate to keep asking, currently your standard errors are quite big so first check to see if you like that better

```
ggplot(new.data, aes(x = timeseries, y = fit)) + geom_line(aes(color=Species))
```

Comment: That is great! Thanks for the help. As for the geom_ribbon function can the predictIntervals be used outside of ggplot2? Just I am using a GLMM and am not hugely familiar with running them in GGPLOT2. What I am aiming to achieve is a predicted probability of each of the species in question, with bootstrapped confidence intervals around the lines. But I am quite new to R and so unclear how I could integrate the above intervals across each species regression line.

Comment: @JamieMurphy if you could share the dataset it would be a lot simpler to help you, but in escence you would have to create a new dataset for each species, I will try to do it with the example dataset in R

Comment: Sorry, I thought I'd included the link. Here it is, and thanks again! https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ao69751qWk2CglTZ04pyKGceq5BN

Comment: I am sorry @JamieMurphy I am a bit confused since I have not done glmer with a response variable that is not just a vector instead of the formated version of cbind(Total_Dead, Total_Collected - Total_Dead), can you tell me why you used this format, and where can a read a little bit about it, I am sure I can make the graphs if you fill me in on that

Comment: Hi Derek, sure. I just utilised this method to deal with the proportional aspect of the data. Creating the response variable for the binomial analysis through cbind(Total_Dead, Total_Collect - Total_Dead) Or more accurately Total_Dead,Total_Alive or Success or failure. I followed the advice from R book pages 590, Generalised Mixed models with proportional data.

Comment: @JamieMurphy I think that will be a better help, let me know if it works for you

Comment: That is great! I am just on way home so will try the code then. One question though. Ideally, I'd like an overall species effect not at the individual location level. Can this be achieved by just leave out the locations? and Only including species in the new data?

Comment: It really depends on the model, try it out if it does not work just add it back, hope it works

Comment: Great, thanks. It seems to be working, however I am creating 22 different graphs for each location. What I wish is to have location as the random effect. Y (prob mortality) X year and the general trend against all locations. Is this possible? 
I've uploaded a pic to show what I have thus far from plot-predict function not ggplot2. 
https://1drv.ms/i/s!Ao69751qWk2CglWIQKCVyLb3dyt9

Comment: Hello again @JamieMurphy I think the graph in the link is very confusing, I would use the one I sent you without the ribbon, since they overlap a lot. Usually when you plot the results of a model, in order to show how two variables work you have to fix a third one as the mean (As in GLMs). Of what I saw the predictions of your model are consistent from site to site, and they don't change much, if not you can always use the gridExtra package to make a good combination plot, would you need help with that as well? let me know

Comment: The Gridextra function would allow me to combine all the data onto one plot yes?

Comment: By turning it into a facet plot, yes