# regression line and confidence interval in R: GLMM with several fixed effects

Tags: r, plot, regression, glm, confidence-interval

Somehow as a follow up on the question [Creating confidence intervals for regression curve in GLMM using Bootstrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39322111/creating-confidence-intervals-for-regression-curve-in-glmm-using-bootstrapping), I am interested in getting the correct values of a regression curve and the associated confidence interval curves.

Consider a case where in a GLMM, there is one response variable, two continuous fixed effects and one random effect. Here is some fake data:

```
library (dplyr)

set.seed (1129)
x1 <- runif(100,0,1)
x2 <- rnorm(100,0.5,0.4)
f1 <- gl(n = 5,k = 20)
rnd1<-rnorm(5,0.5,0.1)

my_data <- data.frame(x1=x1, x2=x2, f1=f1)
modmat <- model.matrix(~x1+x2, my_data)
fixed <- c(-0.12,0.35,0.09)

y <- (modmat%*%fixed+rnd1)

my_data$y <- ((y - min (y))/max(y- min (y))) %>% round (digits = 1)
rm (y)
```

The GLMM that I fit looks like this:

```
m1<-glmer (y ~x1+x2+(1|f1), my_data, family="binomial")
summary (m1)
```

> ```
> Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
>  Family: binomial  ( logit )
> Formula: y ~ x1 + x2 + (1 | f1)
>    Data: my_data
>
>      AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
>     65.7     76.1    -28.8     57.7       96 
>
> Scaled residuals: 
>     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
> -8.4750 -0.7042 -0.0102  1.5904 14.5919 
>
> Random effects:
>  Groups Name        Variance  Std.Dev. 
>  f1     (Intercept) 1.996e-10 1.413e-05
> Number of obs: 100, groups:  f1, 5
>
> Fixed effects:
>             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
> (Intercept)   -9.668      2.051  -4.713 2.44e-06 ***
> x1            12.855      2.659   4.835 1.33e-06 ***
> x2             4.875      1.278   3.816 0.000136 ***
> ---
> Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
>
> Correlation of Fixed Effects:
>    (Intr) x1    
> x1 -0.970       
> x2 -0.836  0.734
> convergence code: 0
> boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular
> ```

Plotting y vs x1:

```
plot (y~x1, my_data)
```

[image]

It should be possible to get a regression curve from the summary of m1. I have learned that I need to reverse the link-function (in this case, "logit"):

```
y = 1/(1+exp(-(Intercept+b*x1+c*x2)))
```

In order to plot a regression curve of x1 in a two-dimensional space, I set `x2 = mean(x2)` in the formula (which also seems important - the red line in the following plots ignores x2, apparently leading to considerable bias). The regression line:

```
xx <- seq (from = 0, to = 1, length.out = 100)
yy <- 1/(1+exp(-(-9.668+12.855*xx+4.875*mean(x2))))
yyy <- 1/(1+exp(-(-9.668+12.855*xx)))

lines (yy ~ xx, col = "blue") 
lines (yyy~ xx, col = "red")
```

[image]

I think, the blue line looks not so good (and the red line worse, of course). So as a side-question: is `y = 1/(1+exp(-(Intercept+b*x1+c*x2)))` always the right choice as a back-transformation of the logit-link? I am asking because I found this https://sebastiansauer.github.io/convert_logit2prob/, which made me suspicious. Or is there another reason for the model not to fit so well? Maybe my data creation process is somewhat 'bad'.

What I need now is to add the 95%-confidence interval to the curve. I think that Bootstrapping using the `bootMer` function should be a good approach. However, all examples that I found were on models with one single fixed effect. @Jamie Murphy asked a similar question, but he was interested in models containing a continuous and a categorical variable as fixed effects here: [Creating confidence intervals for regression curve in GLMM using Bootstrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39322111/creating-confidence-intervals-for-regression-curve-in-glmm-using-bootstrapping)

But when it comes to models with more than one continuous variables as fixed effects, I get lost. Perhaps someone can help solve this issue - possibly with a modification of the second part of this tutorial:
https://www.r-bloggers.com/2015/06/confidence-intervals-for-prediction-in-glmms/

Comment: In your `lines` commands you have switched x and y. They need to be the other way around.

Comment: `library(ggeffects); pr <- ggpredict(m1, "x1", type = "fixed"); plot(pr, add.data = TRUE) ` Might be of interest. Unfortunately, the confidence interval doesn't seem to be a rough approximation and I'm not sure it takes the mixed-model structure well into account.

Comment: Replace "doesn't" with "does".

Comment: About the syntax in the lines argument - are you sure? The regression lines fit much worse then...

Comment: Yes, I'm sure...

Comment: I edited my question. I am quite unsure now why the model performs that bad. Perhaps the data I generated do not really fit the case I want to illustrate?

Comment: `ggpredict` might yield a good solution, thank you @Roland. I only get error messages when applying the function on an averaged model (which is my final goal): `Error in predict.averaging(model, newdata = data, type = type, se.fit = TRUE, : 
 predict' for models '16', '14' and '8' caused errors`. I do not really now what to do about it, because the error is so generalistic.

Comment: I don't think model averaging is supported. I'm not sure marginal effects for ensemble models is even a thing.

Comment: So you mean: it might be the case that there is no way to get confidence intervals for ensemble models (such as averaged models) due to the fact that it simply doesn't make sense?

Comment: My issue is that I have no idea what a marginal effect of an ensemble model actually *is*. Without knowing that, discussion of CIs is moot.

Comment: I suggest you ask for advice at stats.stackexchange.com. At its core this is not a programming issue.